# onClick refresh a div with random line of text from "quotes.txt"

Tags: javascript, php

I have a quote generator at http://communitychessclub.com. I want the user  to be able to click on the quote and load another random quote w/o refreshing the entire page. How can I do this?

```
<h3>

<?php $randomThings = file('quotes.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); 
echo $randomThings[mt_rand(0,count($randomThings)-1)];?>

</h3>
```

I tried colin shoens suggestion below with:

```
<div id="new-projects"></div>
<script>
$( "#new-projects" ).load( "quotes.txt" );
</script>
```

But it loaded all 307 quotes instead of a single random quote.

http://communitychessclub.com/test.php

How can I fix this?

Comment: How many quotes are there? Can you make a dedicated quotes.php with just the above code?

Comment: I have 307 quotes. Yes I can use php to echo and run the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you have over 300 quotes, so an inline JS array of quotes on the client-side page is probably not efficient. Here's a quick solution using jQuery and PHP:

**PHP - quotes.php**

```
<?php 
    // This is your original PHP code, mostly
    $randomThings = file('quotes.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); 
    echo $randomThings[mt_rand(0,count($randomThings)-1)];
?>
```

**HTML side**

```
<H3 id="new-projects"></H3>
<script>
    $( "#new-projects" ).on("click", function(){
       $(this).load( "quotes.php" );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use AJAX which stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. You can use the jQuery library to reduce the amount of code you need right to asynchronously load the new content. Have a look at the jQuery documentation:

https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

A more responsive way would be to load the whole file when the user opens the page, and just have the lines be in an array. Then you can use JavaScript to change the div based on that array, you never have to refresh the page or even contact the server with AJAX.